# Bootstrap carousel different height images cause bouncing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I've been using Bootstrap 3.3.7v's carousel class and it has been 
   straightforward so far, however one problem I've had is that images of 
   different heights cause the divs under it bounce and the images are 
   overflowing out the carousel. I have googled and followed some of answers in 
   stackoverflow, but those not solved my problem. I request anyone briefly 
   explain the issue.

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding:0px;">             
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-    
ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" 
class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">  

<div class="item active">
  <img src="images/slider/1.jpg" alt="blue">      
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="images/slider/2.jpg" alt="purple">     
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="images/slider/3.jpg" alt="red">     
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="images/slider/4.jpg" alt="red">     
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="images/slider/5.jpg" alt="red">     
</div>  
</div>

<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" 
role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" 
role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why dont you specify the height of images...

Comment: @Ashishsah, should I use like this <img src="images/slider/5.jpg" height='250px' alt="red"> ??

Comment: can you upload your code in jsbin or jsfiddle and provide the link?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the css of the images to cover the carousel and then set a maximum height on the carousel.

```
img{
object-fit:cover;
object-position:center;
}

.item{
width:100%
height:100%
}

.carousel{
width:100%
min-height:500px;
max-height:860px;
}
```

I'm not sure about Bootstrap 3 but I know BS4 has a .img-fluid class that can fit images too.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I am getting same problem

Comment: @BharathPateru I have edited my code, hopefully this works for you.

Comment: @BharathPateru as mentioned in another comment, if you could add a jsfiddle for us we can help much easier. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the height and width with a style or class

```
<img src='somethng' style="width:50px; height:50px" >
```

Comment: <img src='somethng' style=object-fit:cover;object-position:center"" >

Comment: If I set as you told carousel height is varying in IE to Chrome and images are getting blurr.